# The limit of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf(\frac xn)$ at zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f : [ 0,+\infty) \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be a convex and decreasing function which is continuous at $0$ and $\lim_{x\longrightarrow +\infty}f(x) = -\infty$. Define $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nf(\frac xn)$. Is it true that we always have  $\lim_{x\longrightarrow 0^+} F(x) = \frac 12f(0)$.

Comment: By the trivial criterium, the series limit does not exist unless $f(0)=0$. Are you per chance using an extended generalized convergence condition?

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left[f(\frac xn)-f(0)\right]$ converges by the Leibniz criterion. By the same criterion, the limit of the series is contained between $f(0)-f(x)$ and $f(\frac x2)-f(x)$, giving the convergence to $0$ for $x\to0$.

Which kind of weak limit do you use?

---

The Cesaro limit of a sequence is actually an often used tutorial exercise. For a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ it is defined as

$$x_*=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_N}N.$$

If the sequence converges in the usual sense, then also $x_*=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$. If the sequence alternates between $0$ and $1$, then the Cesaro limit is $\frac12$.

The difference between the partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n f(\frac xn)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \left[f(\frac xn)-f(0)\right]$ oscillates between $-f(0)$ for odd $N$ and $0$ for even $N$. Thus the Cesaro limit is the limit of the convergent sequence minus $\frac12f(0)$,

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\left(1-\tfrac{n-1}N\right)(-1)^n f\left(\tfrac xn\right)=-\tfrac12f(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left[f\left(\tfrac xn\right)-f(0)\right].$$

Comment: What do you mean !?

Comment: In your formula, the first term for $n=0$ reads as $f(\frac x0)$. -- The trivial necessary condition for the convergence of a series is that its terms converge to zero. $f(\frac xn)$ converges to $f(0)$, because of the continuity of $f$ at $x=0$. So to make sense, you must be using some generalized limit like Cesaro summation.

Comment: That was a typo, I have corrected it.